# Dropdown menu not working with Bootstrap 4 and Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am using Laravel 6 and Bootstrap 4. The dropdown menu in the right side of my navbar worked fine until I ran the command `npm install`. After that the dropdown menu stopped working... when I click on it nothing happen. In the dropdown menu there are the name of the connected user and the logout.

**layout:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden; ">
    <div id="app">
        @include('../inc/navbar')
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        @include('../inc/footer')
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**navbar:**

```
            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @else <!-- This dropdown menu doesn't work-->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                            {{ Auth::user()->name . ' ' . Auth::user()->surname }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Logout') }}
                            </a>

                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endguest
            </ul>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

So currently I cannot logout from the app because the dropdown menu doesn't work.
I read on internet to find the solution and I think that the problem is Popper. How may I configure Popper to solve that problem making the dropdown menu work?

Comment: Can you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: I ran it but the dropdown menu doesn't work.

Comment: The pulldown navbar didn't work for me and I came across this post while I searched for a solution and the answer there worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783007/uncaught-typeerror-bootstraps-dropdowns-require-popper-js-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 14):

It's because you are currently using bootstrap 4 previous version (4.0.0) in your layout.

> **Laravel presets always use latest version.**

So just replace your Bootstrap jQuery & JavaScript CDN scripts with the **latest version** (Currently 4.4.x).

**Add in your layout file:**

Just add these latest jQuery & JavaScript CDN scripts in your layout file and your dropdown menu will start working.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the preset package for front-end scalfolding in Laravel 6

```
php artisan preset bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also and none of the answers worked for me.

I just putted jquery on top of all the scripts:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Everything works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

First check your css and js file location is perfect.
then you change
data-bs-toggle="dropdown" to ​data-toggle="dropdown". I hope it will be help you.

Answer (score 0):

update script & link Bootstrapnya

Comment: kamal, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you are using older version of bootstrap use Bootstrap 5

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
```

The provided HTML code appears to be a part of a navigation menu with a dropdown for user authentication. If the dropdown is not working as expected, there could be several reasons for this issue. Here are some common troubleshooting steps you can take:

Check JavaScript and CSS: Ensure that you have included the necessary JavaScript and CSS files for the dropdown functionality. It seems that this dropdown is using Bootstrap's dropdown component (data-bs-toggle="dropdown"), so make sure you have included Bootstrap's JavaScript and CSS files in your project.

Check for JavaScript Errors: Open the browser's developer console (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect") and look for any JavaScript errors that might be causing issues with the dropdown.

Check Bootstrap Version: Ensure that you are using the correct version of Bootstrap. If you are using Bootstrap 5, make sure that the data-bs-toggle attribute is used correctly. In Bootstrap 5, the data-bs-toggle attribute should be set to "dropdown".

Check Dependencies: If you are using other JavaScript libraries or frameworks, make sure they are not conflicting with Bootstrap's functionality.

Verify HTML Structure: Ensure that the HTML structure is correct. The code you provided appears to be within a  element, which should be inside a  element if it's part of a navigation menu.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541