# Navbar dropdown in Laravel 8 doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with the navbar in Laravel 8; specifically the whole navbar is shown on the view but the dropdown is not working.

In fact, when I click, the drop-down menu does not open.

This is **layout.blade.php**:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <x-navbar/>
    
    {{$slot}}

    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is **navbar.blade.php**:

```js
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and the home.blade.php view is:

```js
<x-layout>
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1>
</x-layout>
```

Comment: Do you have bootstrap js and css in your files? Maybe try with CDN

Comment: in app.css I entered this: @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem with 7.x/8.x.  The dropdown appears correctly with a downward arrow next to the label, but nothing happens when clicked.  Mouseover it just shows the page's url appended with a pound sign (#) at the status line.

Comment: I came across this post and the answer there worked for me.  Hope it'll help you to resolve your problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783007/uncaught-typeerror-bootstraps-dropd
owns-require-popper-js-when-click-on-button

Comment: @Shiping Tried but it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: @Aurora just in case I added more info as a post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this otherwise it might be a typo.

```
      @include('inc.navbar')
//      @include('FOLDER_NAME.FILE_NAME')
```

Also check documentation! https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#including-subviews

Comment: No, this is still used in Laravel 9.x please check laravel documentation! This is answer  to your question. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#including-subviews

Comment: ok but i don't need to include a view within another view. I have <x-layout> doing this for me

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as an answer.  Just to give some info that can't be formatted properly (or I don't know how to) in a comment.  When view the source of the page in a browser, you should see the following three lines in the <head> section (or in other proper location). My navbar dropdown didn't work until these three lines showed up in the source.  Initially I added the lines in a wrong blade file and they didn't end up in the page as expected.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem after altering the app.blade.php header scripts. Upgrading the bootstrap.min.js from 4.6.2 to 5.3.2 solved the problem and the drop down started working again. The particular script I used was:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-WW8/jxkELe2CAiE4LvQfwm1rajOS8PHasCCx+knHG0gBHt8EXxS6T6tJRTGuDQVnluuAvMxWF4j8SNFDKceLFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

from

[cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries?q=bootstrap)

where bootstrap@5.3.2 is currently shown on the right.

Moving from Bootstrap 4 to 5 removes support for Internet Explorer. Best to read about the differences and test to ensure reliability.